# Prove formula from Pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics

I found this in my Norwegian mathematics book. I have solved a)-d) but am stuck at e). Nice if you have feedback on what I have attempted to do.

a) Where are the numbers of the form $\binom{k}{l}$ in Pascal's triangle? Where are the numbers of the form $\binom{k}{2}$? In general, if i is a fixed number and k varies, where will you find the numbers $\binom{k}{i}$?

My answer: I find it on the third diagonal line from the left. If i is fixed, you find it on the ith diagonal line from the left

b) Check through some examples that the following equality seems to hold:

$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k}{i} = \binom {n+1}{i+1}$

Can you explain it through Pascals triangle?

My answer: 
$\sum_{k=2}^4\binom{k}{2}=\binom{5}{3}=10$

In Pascal's triangle this is the sum all from the third diagonal line from the left up to k=4.

The result is $\binom {n+1}{i+1}$

c) Prove the formula b) by induction on n.

My answer:

The equation holds for n. Assuming that the equation also holds for n+1.

$\sum_ {k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i+1}+\binom{n+1}{i}$
$=\frac{(n+1)!}{(i+1)!(n+1)!}+\frac{(n+1)!}{i!(n+1-i)!}$

$=\frac{(n+1)!(n+1-i)}!{(i+1)!(n+1-i)!}+\frac{(n+1)!(i+1)}{(i+1)!(n+1-i)!}$

$=\frac{(n+1)!(n+1-i+i+1)}{(i+1)!(n+1-i)!}$

$=\frac{(n+2)!}{(i+1)!((n+2)-(i+1))!}$

$=\binom{n+2}{i+1}$
This is correct according to Pascal's triangle.

d) Show that the formula can be rewritten to:
$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)(k-2)\dots (k-i+1)=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)\dots(n-i+1)}{i+1}$

My thoughts: Multiply by (n-i)! / (k-1)! on both sides.

$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k}{i} = \binom {n+1}{i+1}$

$\sum_{k=i}^n\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}\dot (k-i)!=\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)(k-2)\dots(k-i+1)$

$\binom {n+1}{i+1}\dot (n-i)!=\frac{(n+1)!}{(i+1)!(n-i)!}\dot (n-1)!$

$=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)\dots(n-i+1)}{i+1}$

e) Show how the formula in d) can be used to find expressions for the sums $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$, $\sum_{k=1}^nk^3$ etc. Hint: Start with the formula

$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

And work your way up the potentials.

My thoughts: I just know how to get the formula $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: E.g. you can write $k^2=k(k-1)+k$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^nk$

Comment: @drhab Then what is $\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)$ ?

Comment: That you find under d) with  $i=2$. Be aware that there is typo in your question there. It should start with $k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots$ (not  $k(k-2)(k-2)\cdots$).

Answer (score 2):

I have the solution for $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$

$k^2=k(k-1)+k$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)+\sum_{k=1}^nk$

$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)(k-2)\dots (k-i+1)=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)\dots(n-i+1)}{i+1}$

$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)=\frac{(n+1)n}{2+1}=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{3}$

$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{3}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{2(n+1)n(n-1)}{3*2}+\frac{3n(n+1)}{2*3}=\frac{n(n+1)(2(n-1)+3))}6=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

The solution for $\sum_{k=1}^nk^3$
$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)(k-2))=\sum_{k=1}^nk^3-\sum_{k=1}^n3k^2+2\sum_{k=1}^n3k=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}{4}$

$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3 -3\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 + 2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}{4}$

$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}{4}+3\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6-2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$\frac{2(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}{8}+4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}8-8\frac{n(n+1)}{8}$

$=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

Comment: +1 Excellent. The hockey stick identity is a nice tool in combinatorics.